# How to check whether redirection is successful or not?

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'd like to check if redirection is successful or not.
I'm redirecting by changing `window.location.href` attribute.

I checked the server status before redirect using XHR.
Is there any other way to check whether the redirect was successful or not?

Plus, if the redirect fails, is the window changed?

1. index.html : change `window.location.href`
2. Redirect fails
3. Is the window the same with index.html?

Comment: just let it redirect

Comment: are you redirecting to an external site, or are you redirecting to a different page within your own site?

Comment: I'm try to redirect to external site.